# Create a <div> on top of another <div>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div (text) on top of another div (rotated white plane). When I create a new div the text is being placed behind and on a lower layer as the previous plane. This is the current website (I'm trying to get text under the bottle image):
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBIlx.png)

**My code (CSS & HTML):**

```css
/* Navigation Bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.topnav a.logo {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a.index:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #FC8E11;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: arial;
}


/* Body settings */

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #FFFF;
  height: 2000px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.plane {
  background-color: white;
  width: 120%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  height: 370px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -140px;
  left: -10%;
}

.plane2 {
  background-color: #FC8E11;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 870px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -5;
}

.titletext {
  text-align: middle;
}

.product_image {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 800px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 220px;
}

.tekst {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!--Navigation Bar-->
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="/images/logo_groot.png" alt="logo" width="48" height="48" align="left"></a>
  <a class="index active" href="index.html">Over ons</a>
  <a class="index" href="verkooplocaties.html">Verkooplocaties</a>
  <a class="index" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <!--Illustration-->
  <div class="product_image">
    <img src="/images/illustration.png" width="800px" height="800px">
  </div>

  <!--Planes-->
  <div class="plane2"></div>
  <div class="plane"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <!--Text-->
  <div class="tekst">
    <p> Heb je tijdens het sporten sleutels of pin- & sportpassen bij je? Hinderen deze spullen je soms bij het sporten? BottleBuidel is een houder voor je drinkfles waar je deze spullen in kan bewaren tijdens het sporten. Door de flexibele stof past de BottleBuidel
      om iedere sportfles en kun je daardoor altijd je spullen bij je houden zonder dat je deze hoeft te bewaren in je broekzakken of op de grond. De BottleBuidel is gemaakt van geupcyclede (gewassen!) sportbroeken waardoor het bijdraagt aan een duurzamere
      wereld! Meer informatie over het product, verkooplocaties en de prijs is te vinden op de product pagina.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use the z-index value with positive numbers, and different values for your different planes. The lowest positive value will be on the lowest priority layer.

Comment: Thank you for the help @TorjescuSergiu. Unfortunately when I set the z-index to positive values (orange plane = 1, bottle image = 2, rotated white plane = 3), I'm no longer seeing the bottle image (even though it's located correctly)

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve? https://codepen.io/torjescu-sergiu/pen/jOPYvwO

Comment: Something similar. I can place text on top of the rectangle planes in your example with no problem. However, when I place text on the div in my personal project it will be rotated (since the plane is rotates aswell):
http://prntscr.com/re599q

I thought that the solution for this is creating a new div, on top of the rotated div. However, I'm not sure if that works and how to do that.

I'm trying to create this:
http://prntscr.com/re5dot
(I quickly photoshopped the image to show what I'm looking for in the end)

Answer (score 0):

you can try giving z-index to the div maybe z-index is the order of something in the z dimension lets say if you want the second div to be in front you can give it the z-index of one

the code looks like this:

```css
z-index:1;
```